# GIT pull not showing any changes

Tags: git, tortoisegit

We are using bit bucket as a repository. Below is a scenario we got.

1. Pull from Branch A (commit already in Develop Branch of A) -> B (git pull origin A)
2. Reverted commit in branch B of A (git revert)
3. Now i want same commit in branch B, hence creating pull from Develop -> B
   But so no changes available to pull.

How do i resolve this situation?

I have tried merge, git pull but still no chances.

Comment: The question is unclear: Are A and B remotes/repos or branches?

Comment: Yes, both are branches

Answer (score 0):

Remember to run the `git fetch --all` command to retrieve all changes if there are any, then try again.

Comment: `--all` means *all remotes*. The OP has only one remote (`origin`), so `--all` has no effect.

Comment: I believe that `--all` should still work because it means to fetch all branches from all remotes.

Comment: `--all` *just* means "all remotes"; it has no effect on the set of branches, which are determined by the refspecs. The OP's actual issue is that he's added a revert commit, and is expecting a second merge of the old already-reverted commit to do something it won't do.

Comment: This is just wrong. `fetch --all` doesn't mean what you (@NewbieCody) think it does, and it won't change anything about the OP's situation.

Comment: Hi Torek & Matt, thanks for suggestion. I think i can do cherry pick commit from Develop.